# mongoDB: aggregation which adds a field of counting field in the collection

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDb and have a query which I am struggling with.. 
I have a collection of reported users which looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "userId": 1,
  "reason": "some reason",
  "date": "2017-07-22"
}
```

I need a query which will add to each report the number of reports for that userId.
meaning if the collection has 3 records with userId=1. the query will return three records and each of them will also include a field 
count=3 meaning the record above will now look like this:

```
{
  "_id": 1
  "userId": 1,
  "reason": "some reason",
  "date": "2017-07-22",
  "count": 3
}
```

I tried using $project and $addFields aggregations but was not able to add a field which is a result of a query over the whole collection.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by Veeram is correct, just that if you are running mongodb version less than 3.6, in the last stage of aggregate you might want to replace the $replaceRoot operator with a $project

```
aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$userId", "data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}, count:{$sum:1} } },
{"$unwind":"$data"},
{$project:{_id:"$data._id", userId:"$data.userId", reason:"$data.reason", date:"$data.date", count:1}}
])
```